# Pinging an Endpoint Behind a Redirecting Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I'm attempting to find the route time between my laptop and a couple of endpoints for benchmarking purposes.

Example:

I have an Anycast IP (1.2.3.4) that has been provisioned for me by AWS Global Accelerator. In addition, I have a public IP address on the EC2 instance itself that I can reach. When requests hit the Anycast IP, they are then redirected to my EC2 instance.

What I'm trying to test:

```
computer (ping) -> EC2 Instance (time in ms)
computer (ping) -> Anycast IP -> EC2 Instance (time in ms)
```

Is there a simple way to follow redirects and get ping times?

Comment: That is not what ping is for. Ping is designed to test network connectivity, and the RTT for ping is for ICMP, not a protocol that you would use in an application. ICMP is a pretty low-priority protocol, and you simply cannot compare it to something like TCP of UDP that you would use in an application.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Do you have any guidance as to how I can pragmatically get some latency values?

Comment: There are tools that "ping" using a different protocol, such as TCP. You could also write a small application that tries to open a TCP connection to a port you know is not used on the target, and you should get RST back, and you could calculate the time between the send of SYN and reception of the RST.

Comment: *"When requests hit the Anycast IP, they are then redirected to my EC2 instance."*  The "requests" are not being "redirected" -- Global Accelerator provides its service using combined source+dest NAT -- so there are no redirects to follow.  It isn't clear what you are referring to with the phrase "follow redirects."

Comment: Hey Michael. Could you go a bit deeper into the source+dest NAT? I thought it just redirected requests through AWSs fabric to the desired endpoint.